# Using NSDateComponents/NSCalendar to decipher weeks of a month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I've been playing around with `NSDates` and need to compare if two dates are in the same week.
So far I've managed to use the `[NSDateComponents week]` to check if they are WITHIN a week of each other. However I need to be able to check instead if they are in the same week of a month, e.g. `week 1 {monday-sunday}`. `week 2 {monday-sunday}`.

Is this possible in iOS?

Comment: What if the dates are in the same week, but in different month, e.g. "Thursday Feb 28" and "Friday March 1"? Does that count as "within a week"?

Comment: What about "Monday December 12, 2012" and "Tuesday, January 1, 2013"? Does that count as within a week?

Comment: I've found a nice way to do it - [[cal components: NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate: myDate] week];

Comment: Isn't that exactly what DBD has suggested in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

While this sound suspiciously like it might be a homework assignment. I think this is what you want, but if you only want it to be part of the 3rd week (or whatever) and it doesn't matter which month it's in; you can take out the month part.

```
// Assume date1 and date2 are NSDates

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *date1Components = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:date2];

if (date1Components.week == date2Components.week &&
    date1Components.month == date2Components.month) {
    // same week of same month
} else {
    // either different week or different month (or both)
}
```

For more information on this, check out Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW1)